# Is oid claim of microsoft oidc id token the same as id get from me of microsoft graph api?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

[About oid claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims) decoded from access token/id token of azureAD:

> .... *This ID uniquely identifies the user across applications - two different applications signing in the same user will receive the same value in the oid claim.* ... *Note that if a single user exists in multiple tenants, the user will contain a different object ID in each tenant - they're considered different accounts, even though the user logs into each account with the same credentials.* ...

[About `id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#common-properties) get from `/me` of microsoft graph api:

> The unique identifier for the user.

Previously, one of my application uses `oid` from id token as the id of azure user.
Now, I want to update and use `id` of graph api for the same purpose. So:

- Are these two ids (`oid` and `id`) is the same? So I can replace `oid` by `id`?
- Does `id` get from `/me` is different for "each tenant", as `oid` description above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, oid and id should be same, at least for AAD users.

But it is different in each AAD tenant where you are a member. It uniquely identifies the specific user object globally, and each user object is separate in each tenant.

There is a possibility to include the "home tenant oid" via the Token configuration blade in the app registration. 
That will then be the oid of the user in their home tenant, i.e. the tenant where the user was created.