# Is id for User for Microsoft Account is the same as oid claim in ID Token?

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

`id` in *Azure AD* [User object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) is the same value as `oid` claim in [ID Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) as answered in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60170062/1014818), but the situation seems to differ from the users for *Microsoft Account*.

Microsoft Graph API (`/me`) returns `id` as, for example, `0123456789abcdef`, but `oid` in ID Token for the same user is a UUID-formatted string (`00000000-0000-0000-0123-456789abcdef`).

I'd like to know if I can judge whether two differently formatted ID is the same one or not.

```
$ curl https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me -H 'Authorization: Bearer ...' | jq .
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "displayName": "",
  "surname": "",
  "givenName": "",
  "id": "0123456789abcdef",
  "userPrincipalName": "user@example.com",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": null
}
```

```
{
  "ver": '2.0',
  "iss": 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0',
  "sub": '...',
  "aud": 'xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  "exp": 1668257519,
  "iat": 1668170819,
  "nbf": 1668170819,
  "preferred_username": "user@example.com",
  "oid": "00000000-0000-0000-0123-456789abcdef",
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "tid": "xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "nonce": "...",
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryobject?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), the user id (inherited from directoryObject) is the unique identifier for the object and the value of the id property is **often but not exclusively in the form of a GUID**; treat it as an opaque identifier and do not rely on it being a GUID.

`oid` claim is same as `user id` but always in the form of a GUID.

Based on that `0123456789abcdef` is same as `00000000-0000-0000-0123-456789abcdef`. `00000000-0000-0000-0123-456789abcdef` represents formatted value of `0123456789abcdef`.

Comment: Thanks. I built a system with SSO feature using Microsoft Account. I want to migrate from the fields in `/me` to the claims in ID token but was very confused because two APIs return the same `id` value in different format. Can I safely assume they can be converted each other?

Comment: @okapies yes, they can be converted